# CORS Issue: Pull Spring/MySQL Backend from DockerHub For Front End Development

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, docker, docker-compose

I have pushed a java/mysql backend application to my private dockerhub. I would like to sandbox this so multiple users can access, and make API calls to this application as we would like to do some front-end browser development in React. Using a REST client like Postman is fine, but when we start using the browser we start having CORS issues:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/simulations/1/ratings/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  footysim-db:
    restart: always
    container_name: footysim-db
    image: 'mysql:5.7.30'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: football_simulation
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    volumes:
      - './initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql'
  footysim-server:
    restart: always
    image: 'DOCKERHUB:PROJECT'
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://footysim-db:3306/football_simulation?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - footysim-db
```

And in my `application-properties` in Spring Boot:

```
project.cors.allowedOrigins=http://$server_ip:3000, http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Have I done something wrong with the config?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue in the past. It was not related to docker though.
As a work around to allow CORS functionality i added a custom filter in which i defined a specific API path to be allowed with CORS headers.

Code snippet below:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getServletPath();
        if(path.contains("abcd- api path after contextPath ")||path.contains("abcd- api path after contextPath  ")) {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Imran. Along the same lines I found this to be the solution:

```
  @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```